# Unable to create a simple database in mySQL

Tags: mysql, database, syntax-error

```
CREATE DATABASE 'hello' ;
```

> 19:40:38  CREATE DATABASE 'hello' Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''hello'' at line 1

I installed mysql with default settings and I don't know if it has anything to do with the settings.

Can someone tell me how to fix this error?

Comment: `'hello'` is a string literal. Identifiers are not quoted in SQL. Details are in the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html

Comment: Correct, try `CREATE DATABASE hello;`

Comment: If you must `quote` the database name, then use back ticks **`**

Comment: Oh that was a silly question.What a noob Im.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic syntax of CREATE DATABASE statement is as follows:

```
        CREATE DATABASE DatabaseName;
```

Try Like Below...

```
        CREATE DATABASE hello;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this;

```
 CREATE DATABASE hello;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html